# How to filter the result of a SELECT query further?

Tags: mysql

Okay, so I have this simple Mysql query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student
LEFT JOIN student_state ON student.student_id = student_state.student_id_fk
WHERE student_surname LIKE '%XXX%' 
   OR student_lastname LIKE '%XXX%'
```

And it returns some results.

I want to take these results and filter it further with a second select like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT student_payment 
     FROM student
     LEFT JOIN student_state ON student.student_id = student_state.student_id_fk
     WHERE student_surname LIKE '%XXX%' 
        OR student_lastname LIKE '%XXX%') AS test 
WHERE  
    student_payment LIKE '%XXX%' 
    OR student_unlock  LIKE '%XXX%'
```

When I just insert the first `SELECT` into the `FROM` brackets, I get an error that an alias is needed. When I provide an alias to the subquery, it says

> Unknown column student_payment or student_unlock

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the broken attempts and error messages verbatim. Can't diagnose what we can't see.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a a seconds select.  Add the constraints to your 1st query.

Comment: You probably just want to use parentheses to group the `or`'d part of the logic. You don't include `student_unlock` as output from the inner query which is why that part is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1st query returns only 1 column but in the 2nd you try to filter by 2 columns.
So include both columns is your 1st query:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT student_payment, student_unlock 
  FROM student LEFT JOIN student_state 
  ON student.student_id = student_state.student_id_fk
  WHERE student_surname LIKE '%XXX%' OR student_lastname LIKE '%XXX%'
) t
WHERE t.student_payment LIKE '%XXX%' OR t.student_unlock  LIKE '%XXX%'
```

You can get the same results with this:

```
SELECT student_payment, student_unlock 
FROM student LEFT JOIN student_state 
ON student.student_id = student_state.student_id_fk
WHERE 
  (student_surname LIKE '%XXX%' OR student_lastname LIKE '%XXX%')
  AND
  (t.student_payment LIKE '%XXX%' OR t.student_unlock  LIKE '%XXX%')
```

Comment: But why do this? Just add more conditions to the existing query.

Comment: I don't know why the OP wants separate filters. I guess there must be a reason.

Comment: I guess there may not be ;)

Comment: @forpas sorry, i had an error in my post, it should be * instead of "student_payment"
LightnessRacesinOrbit If i connect everything with ORs, then i do not get the exclusive results where (OR OR OR ) AND ( OR OR OR)  is true. With ORs, ists just the left side, both or the other side

Comment: yes, but it says "unknown column t.student_payment" :/

Comment: That cannot be.

Comment: Is there such a column in any of the 2 tables?

Comment: Sorry nevermind! I found my error. I need to select in the subquery explicit the outer columns.   * inside does not work on the outside with t.student_payment  and t.student_unlock. Thank you!! :)

Comment: It should do. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Argh yes... you are right. i guess i had some other typo in it. I guess i should be going to bed for today... thank you guys!

Comment: Just change one thing at a time and record what you do!

Comment: And always qualify the column names with the table names.